# Webform with element that has logged in user's username

Tags: 8, webforms

In my D8 site i have several webforms created.
I would like to have a Webform element that will pull/prepopulate logged in user's username. Is there a way to achieve that from GUI?

The reason i want that element is that from within Webform Submissions i would like to be able to filter per Username of the user who submitted the webform. This way username will be included in submission data.

By default it allows filtering webform submissions per submission data only or administrative notes.

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can create a Value element with a token to capture and store the current user's name.

```
name:
 '#title': 'User Name'
 '#type': value
 '#value': '[current-user:name]'
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks @jrockowitz. I will add Token module and give it a try

Comment: It worked perfectly, i did not even have to add token module. Core tokens pulled in the User Name.